# Return first Not NULL value in a partition in a Tableau View

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

In the below dataset I need to return the first not null value for each partition. Can somebody please help.

Dataset:

```
Item    FirstSold   Name
1       NULL        Jack
1       13          Rob
1       2           Simon
2       NULL        Mat
2       6           Erik
2       12          Rob
3       NULL        Jack
3       9           Gon
3       9           ob
4       NULL        Erik
4       NULL        Rob
4       12          Jack
```

Output:

```
Item    Name
1       Rob
2       Erik
3       Gon
4       Jack
```

Is there anyway to establish this using LOD?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Used the below LOD expression based on MAX and MIN  if [Key]=[D1. Min Key] and [D3. Max Key NULL]=False and [D2. Min Key NULL]=False then "Y"

elseif [D3. Max Key NULL]=True and [Actv Flag]="Y" and [D2. Min Key NULL]=True then "Y"

else "N"

END; but unable to figure out when MAX and Min value are both different.

Comment: If your calculation depends on the ordering of rows in the query result, then you need to either use table calcs or some sort of custom SQL. Try table calcs first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Place First Sold in to filter and exclude `Null`, Which will remove null and retrives just not null.
2. Create a calculation field and use function `First()` and then go to `Edit Table Calculation` there select all 3 fields used in table and then reset the table for every `Item`.
3. Place the table calculation on the filter and then select only `0` now you have your first not null value in report

Comment: You probably want to also decide how to sort the “compute using” fields in your table calc, rather than leave it unspecified — i.e. define first ...

Comment: @AlexBlakemore good catch.. yes we can even do that sort in datasource order

Comment: Even if using data source order, that can change arbitrarily unless you specify it. If you are using custom SQL or a view, you can of course have an ORDER BY clause -- but I recommend avoiding them in the data source and instead specifying the order in Tableau. That way charts that don't depend on order, don't have to pay the cost to sort and charts that want to display the data in a different order, don't have to first pay the cost to sort one way, before then sorting another way. Let the data source do most of the work, but usually leave the sorting to the client.